# Integrating Visual Studio Code into Cygwin

Tags: visual-studio-code, linux-kernel, cygwin

I was wondering if there was a way to have Visual Studio Code open a file when accessed by Cygwin. For instance, when using an alias to change directories and open a Verilog file, have that file be opened within Visual Studio Code instead. I have very limited experience in Linux, and it looks like Visual Studio Code is easier to navigate/edit scripts, though that could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to open a windows command (that is not in the path) from the cygwin terminal is to create an shell alias to start VSCode or Visual Studio with a filename from the cygwin terminal. Add a line to your `.bashrc` like:

```
alias vscode=<path to vscode>
```

Find `<path to vscode>` by right clicking on the link you use to open VSCode or Visual Studio using the desktop or start menu, and select "More -> Open file location". This will open an explorer window with a shortcut highlighted. Right click on it, and select "Properties". In properties click on the "Open file location" button. In  the resulting explorer windows, use shift-right click on the highlighted file and select "Copy as path".

Back in cygwin, enter

```
cygpath -wa <paste>
```

(In the cygwin terminal, use "Right click -> Paste" or shift-ctrl-C to paste). Then use line editing to change the double quotes to single quotes and run the command. This shows you the string to use as `<path to vscode>` in the alias command. You must restart the cygwin terminal for the alias to be available.

To use this alias, enter e.g.

```
vscode <filename.ext>
```

to open the file is VS Code or Visual Studio. I use similar alias to open an explorer window, or my browser with an html file, or to open a file in Notepad++.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much. I had to change a folder name in the path since there were spaces in but it works great.